# CondaValueError: invalid package specification: nvcc --version=10.1

Tags: anaconda, conda, nvidia, anaconda3, nvcc

when try to create environment in anaconda, input:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Output:

```
CondaValueError: invalid package specification: nvcc --version=10.1
```

enviroment.yml include dependency:

```
  - cudatoolkit=10.1
```

How to solve this problem?

Related information: centos 7.9.2009, CUDA Version: 11.7, NVIDIA-SMI 515.43.04, conda 23.7.4

I notice channels of environment.yml include pytorch, is it because I did not install that?

Comment: Where did you get that environment.yml, it is not formatted correctly.